# c# Equality Order Of Operations

Tags: c#

Are these expressions equivalent?
Assume the letters are all booleans

```
  a == b || c == d || e == f

  (a == b) || (c == d) || (e == f)
```

I've tested with a couple of example which yielded the same result for both but not sure if I'm missing a case that shows the opposite.

Comment: it is the same, the compiler, just like a basic and crude calculator, decides what the right order is for the expressions.

Comment: It's (of course) in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/

Comment: "Are these expressions equivalent?" well no not strictly they do however compile to an equivalent set of/the same code.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Please explain / clarify in which way those are not exactly the same... strictly speaking. They also do not compile to an equivalent but to the exact same thing. The JIT ASM for both is the exact same.

Comment: Pro tip: If you're ever unsure of the order of operations, use parentheses. It's better to be unnecessarily verbose than to assume and be wrong.

Comment: @Max strictly as asked it is the original source code being asked about not the actual compiled code - so the "behavior" is the same but not the source code. Sure a bit picky perhaps but still.  The "results"/logical values are the same but not the source "code".

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thanks for clarifying. I actually interpreted the question differently in that the boolean arithmetic was being questioned.

Comment: @Max very well likely what was meant also - key here is to also ask questions with specific clarity to avoid any alternate interpretation.  I want 3 gold bars onto my front porch each day but wanting really means nothing - and if they are gold colored bars of mud I just have a mess to clean up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, expressions are the same.

```
a == b || c == d || e == f // Expression #1

(a == b) || (c == d) || (e == f) // Is an equivalent of the Expression #1
```

Check out the Operator precedence from the official documentation:

> The following table lists the C# operators starting with the highest precedence to the lowest. The operators within each row have the same precedence.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence

[image: Operator precedence in C#]

Answer (score 1):

One way to understand it is by using https://sharplab.io/.
Sharplab will give you code generated by your code in C#

in this case: This is your code

```
using System;
public class C {
    public void M() {
        
        bool a = false,b = false,c = false,d = false,e = false,f = false;
        
        if (a == b || c == d || e == f){
            Console.Write("1");
        }

        if ((a == b) || (c == d) || (e == f)){
            Console.Write("2");
        }
        
    }
}
```

and this is the generated code:

```
public class C
{
    public void M()
    {
        bool flag = false;
        bool flag2 = false;
        bool flag3 = false;
        bool flag4 = false;
        bool flag5 = false;
        bool flag6 = false;
        if (flag == flag2 || flag3 == flag4 || flag5 == flag6)
        {
            Console.Write("1");
        }
        if (flag == flag2 || flag3 == flag4 || flag5 == flag6)
        {
            Console.Write("2");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a==b||c==d||e==f // This

(a==b)||(c==d)||(e==f) // And this, are exactly the same
```

The order it will check these in is from left to right, meaning it will check `a==b`, and if it's true, and if the rest of them are `||` operators, it will stop checking them, because those are unecessary checks, where it will return true regardless of their outcome.

However, if what you were asking was about this:

```
a==b&&c==d&&e==f
```

This will have to check each statement, because it will return false unless ALL of them are true.

## EDIT:

For clarity, using the `&&` operator, the statement would be checked in this order. First, `a==b` would be checked. If `a==b` is true, it would then check `c==d`. If `c==d` is true, it would then check `e==f`

If `a==b` were false though, it would stop and just return `false`, as all three statements would have to be true, in order for the whole statement to return `true`

Comment: If a is not equal to b, it will **not** stop checking but continue with the next comparison.

Comment: It's possible I'm wrong, but... In my experience, it will stop after it hits a point that the rest of the comparisons don't matter. For the expression `a==b || c==d`, if `a==b` is true, then it is going to return true regardless of `c==d`. From what I understand, it will stop once it reaches a point that the rest of the expressions don't change the outcome, it's an efficiency thing. I use this to check for a null expression, then do the actual comparison on the object in the same if statement, and this helps avoid null reference exceptions. Maybe null checks are a special case though

Comment: Yes, but you wrote: "it will check a==b, and if the rest of them are || operators, it will stop checking them". You did not mention that this holds only when `a==b` is `true`

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, these are interchangeable.

If at least one of the following conditions is true, then both expressions are true.

1. a and b are equal
2. c is equal to d.
3. e equals f

The logical OR operator || is used in both expressions to combine the three requirements. Although they are not absolutely required, the parenthesis in the second expression can assist make the phrase easier to read and avoid possible operator precedence problems.